# Deploying my first app is giving me a blackscreen

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Im completly new to Android App development and need help to get on my feet to start my first project.

So I just created a simple project, a blank app android project in visual studio.
And when i try to deploy it, it doesnt want to start up, and it doesnt show the error in the solution explorer.

Here if the first picture

[image: Here if the first picture]

And this is what it looks like

[image: And this is what it looks like]

Comment: When I press yes on the error message it says deploy failed and makes a red rectangle around the black simulator area

Comment: Add your Build Output : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs  It can point out your error.

Comment: Could this be annotated in some way such that Visual Studio 2015 users can do the same? I tried to "translate" from this IDE to VS2015 and failed to see detailed diagnostics.

Comment: Im going to try to install Xamarin Android Player. Keep coming with answers, becase im not sure that mine will fix it, will let you know if it does!

Comment: Show me your build log from VS :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651643.aspx

Comment: I dont seem to have one, even though I've built the project several times, I will keep looking. And yes I tried following that guide, did not locate me to the file needed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution.

If you havent already install this
https://xamarin.com/android-player

If you are still getting error, update the oracle VM VirtualBox to 5.0.16

And if you are still having issues, restart your PC and it will work!